# Sheafification and monomorphisms.

Tags: category-theory, sheaf-theory

I was showing that a monomorphism of sheaves induces a monomorphism in stalks. I used the classical fact about filtered colimits but I was wondering that if the inclusion is adjoint to sheafification then it preserves limits, shouldn't it preserve monomorphisms?

In that case a monomorphism of sheaves is the same as a monomorphism of presheaves hence we can get a very simple proof of the statement from above?

I feel like I missing something because this seems way too easy.

Comment: Yes, a mono of sheaves is equivalently a mono of presheaves, although that uses more than the adjunctions to prove the reverse implication, namely that sheafication also preserves finite limits. What's the easy proof using this?

Comment: Well if two elements in the stalk are mapped to the same. That's the same as two sections in some nbh mapped to the same section isnt it?